# using multiple args with docopt

Tags: python, python-3.x, docopt

I'm trying to use `docopt` so a user can do an input like:

```
python3 -p argum1 -d argum2 [-u arg_facul]
```

the arguments `argum1` and `argum` must **not** be positional; the first two arguments are required and the third is optional.

I already have this:

```
""" 
Usage:
         pyprogram.py    (-p PASS | --pass=PASS) (-d DICT | --dict=DICT) [-u USER --user=USER]  

    Arguments:


    Options:
        -p              demand argument 1
        -d              demand argument 2 
        -u              may have this agrument or not
"""
```

The output is:

```
...$ python3 pyprogram.py -d dict.txt -p passwd.txt -u root 
{'--dict': None,  '--pass': None,  '-d': True,  '-p': True,  '-u': True,  'DICT': 'passwd.txt', 'PASS': 'dict.txt', 'USER': 'root'}
```

and I want the output to be:

```
... $ python3 pyprogram.py -d dict.txt -p passwd.txt -u root 
{'--dict': None,  '--pass': None,  '-d': True,  '-p': True,  '-u': True,  'DICT': 'dict.txt',  'PASS': 'passwd.txt', 'USER': 'root'}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `argparse` instead?

Comment: i have to use docopt... and people tell me that docopt is mutch clean, less lines and easyer than argparse...

Comment: The problem is that you imply and order here also. So that that the `dict` has to come after `pass`. That is why you don't get the order you want.

Comment: so i can i do it so that i don't have tu put the args in order?

Answer (score 0):

I have foun out.
Docopt is very piky concerning the space ant tabs.

so here is how it's going to be.

```
"""
Usage:
  passcrack_end.py -p <passw> -d <dic> [-u <user>]

Arguments:
  <passw>   ficheiro onde se encontram as passwords encriptadas - shadow
  <dic>     ficheiros com o dicionario das possiveis palavras passe 
  <user>    Utilizador para o qual quer encontrar a password

Option:
  -p pp     opção obrigatória
  -d dd     opção obrigatória
  -u uu     campo facultativo
"""
```

Watch out for the spaces. in the options the indentations is **2 spaces -d**

if you call the program with this argumentes:

```
-d derivation -p panto -u ume
```

the output will be:

```
{
  "-d": "derivation", 
  "-p": "panto", 
  "-u": "ume"
}
```

if you call the program with this argumentes:

```
 -p panto -u ume -d derivation
```

the output will be the same:

```
{
  "-d": "derivation", 
  "-p": "panto", 
  "-u": "ume"
}
```